# Making an image url save to sql database when image is clicked

Tags: php, sql

I would like to make it so that when you click an image it saves that images url to a field in a database... I know how to do the SQL UPDATE part but i don't know how to get the the image url?

I am sorry but i have no code because i don't know where to start!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can wrap an `anchor` tag (`<a href='insert.php?url=something'></a>`) around the image, or if you don't want to leave the page when you click the image you can do it with `jQuery`,

Comment: Thanks! I will be using both yours and Jazzp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the url of the image with jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('img').click(function(){
       var img = $(this.src)
   });
});
```

Then execute your Ajax request using your var img to send the information in your php file.

Edit: Remember to escape the URL that is going to be returned as someone could easily try and SQL injection or some kind of breach in your database.

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to make an ajax request. In this example i use jQuery:

```
//javascript
$('img').click(function(){
    $.post('process.php', {url: $(this).attr('src')});
}

//process.php
$url = $_POST['url'];
//save to db
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as @Jonan suggested and pass the url you want to save in anchor.

According to @Jonan:

```
<a href="insertPictureURL.php?url=theLinkYouwantToSave"></a>
```

Then all you need to do is get the value and store it in a php variable in "insertPictureURL.php" with:

```
$theLinkIWantToSave = $_GET['url'];
```

Then just put that in your query.